# Update table using inner join with two conditions and copy over two columns

Tags: mysql, inner-join, updates

I have a table `prices` with 1.5 million records and I have a table `flaggedcomments` with 1500 records.

Table `flaggedcomments` has the below columns:

- Flaggedcomments_ID
- Comments_DateTime
- Author
- Comments
- Tickers_Ticker_ID
- Prices_DateTime (empty)
- Prices_Open (empty)

Table `prices` has the below columns (they are all filled in with values):

- Prices_ID
- Prices_DateTime
- Prices_Open
- Tickers_Ticker_ID

Here's my MySQL syntax:

```
UPDATE flaggedcomments t1 
INNER JOIN prices t2 
ON t1.Tickers_Ticker_ID = t2.Tickers_Ticker_ID AND t1.Comments_Date = t2.Prices_DateTime
SET t1.Prices_DateTime = t2.Prices_DateTime, t1.Prices_Open = t2.Prices_Open
```

I want to make sure `Comments_DateTime` in `flaggedcomments` table is match with `Prices_DateTime` in `prices` table; along with `Tickers_Ticker_ID` in both `flaggedcomments` and `prices` are matched, then fill in the `Prices_DateTime` and `Prices_Open` from `prices` table to `flaggedcomments`.

The syntax has been executed since 2 hours ago, and it's still running (doing this in MySQL workbench). I also tried to lookup the `flaggedcomments` from my program's datagridview, the two columns appear to be still fully empty.

I've been correcting my syntax, the current one looks correct but I don't know whether there is any problem with it? Could anyone kindly advise or point the problem out? Or is it merely due to large table?

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit longer (took about 3.5 hours) since `prices` table has such a large records. And the correct syntax is supposed to use `LEFT JOIN` than `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels of indexation. I believe you already have the column `Prices_ID` declared as primary key, so that column already has an clustered index. Each table can have only one clustered index, it affects on the logic how the information is saved in the storage physically and speeds up the queries (the search of rows by `Prices_ID`). So let's think about how to use secondary indexes to speed up your query.

For each row from table `flaggedcomments`, your query(the DBMS) tries to find some rows from the table `prices` that match some condition. So if you add indexes on the columns from the `prices` table that are used in the condition, the DBMS will be able to find the desired rows quickly. That's the index role - store comfortably to find quickly.

```
ALTER TABLE `prices` ADD INDEX (`Tickers_Ticker_ID`);
ALTER TABLE `prices` ADD INDEX (`Prices_DateTime`);
```

So for each row from the table `flaggedcomments`, the DBMS will be able to find the rows from the `prices` table that have the same `Tickers_Ticker_ID` and `Prices_DateTime` more quickly. 
Actually the DBMS will not scan the whole `prices` table by comparing all the rows inside one by one, because being indexed the DBMS already knows the places approximately where to search the desired rows.

These are some helpful mysql links -
How to create indexes - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html
Difference between indexes - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html
B-Tree and indexation logic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: Hi Hovo, thanks for providing me this bit of answer. May I know, did you add index to both `Tickers_Ticker_ID` and `Prices_DateTime` because both tables contain them? Thank you.

Comment: No, and I'll try to explain in my answer why.